# Using '.ToString()' with numeric variables

Tags: c#, string, numeric

Is there any drawback for omitting `.ToString()` while converting numeric values to `string` ?

```
int i = 1234;
string s;
// Instead of
s = "i is " + i.ToString();
// Writing
s = "i is " + i;
```

Comment: In terms of generated IL there is no difference.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this won't compile? `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'`

Comment: Don't you get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'` error?

Comment: @Michael +1. I looked and it and thought "that couldn't possibly compile", but had to pull out visual studio to try. And it didnt

Comment: I'm amazed how many people didn't realize that this won't compile

Comment: @ataddeini: No, there's no compile error.

Comment: @Oskar: I'm using VS 2010 and the code compiles without errors!

Comment: @Xaqron If there is no compile error then I assume your real code is difference? There are things that implicitly call ToString, for example `string.Format("I: {0}", i);` will implicitly call i.ToString(). There are others as well. But straight up assignment won't work.

Comment: @Xaqron There is a compilation error. In visual studio only the "i" is red to indicate the error. Check the error list as well

Comment: @Xaqron, yes, you do get a compiler error.  I suspect you made your sample too simple and changed the meaning of the code.   `s = i` is **completely** different from `s = "" + i`.

Comment: @Xaqron: There isn't? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: That's not the exact code. In real code I concatenate a number with a string: `"Count: " + i` but the question is not about this. I tried to simplify the code. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Xaqron You should really make sure that the code compiles before you put the question here

Comment: @Oscar: I thought about StackOverFlow as a place for discussing concepts, not an online compiler. Anyway, question updated.

Comment: @Xaqron SO is not a place for discussions either. And it's hard to discuss the difference in what something is compiled into if it doesn't compile

Comment: @Xaqron That's a whole different code though. Strong Concatenation implicitly calls `i.ToString()` (I believe it compiles down to a call to `String.Concat("Count: ",i)` which then calls ToString on i), so there is no difference between i and i.ToString()

Comment: @Xaqron StackOverflow is a place to get specific answers to specific questions. The problem is that when the question asked on SO doesn't match the actual question, it's impossible or at least hard to understand what the _real_ question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference in this case.

```
"Count: " + i
```

compiles down to

```
String.Concat("Count: ",i)
```

[String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) has multiple overloads, and I believe that the `Concat(Object, Object)` overload is chosen (since the only common ancestor of string and int is object).

The internal implementation is this:

```
 return (arg0.ToString() + arg1.ToString());
```

If you call

```
"Count: " + i.ToString()
```

then it chooses the `Concat(String, String)` overload since both are strings.

So for all practical matters, it's essentially doing the same anyway - it's implicitly calling i.ToString().

I usually omit .ToString in cases like the above because it just adds noise.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact it won't compile (at least it won't using Visual Studio 2008 without adding another `""` in front of the first `i`) there ARE differences, depending on how you use it (assuming it would work) and in which order operators are handled (in C# and I guess almost all languages `+` has a higher priority than `=`):

```
int i = 1234;
string s;
s = i.ToString(); // "1234"
s = i.ToString() + i.ToString(); // "12341234"
s = i; // "1234"
s = i + i; // "2468" (but only if you don't add "" in front)
```

Edit:
With the updated code there's no real difference assuming you don't use brackets to group several non-string objects/variables:

```
int i = 1234;
string s;
s = "" + i + i; // "12341234"
s = "" + (i + i); // "2468"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback I can think of is that you can put additional parameters to `ToString()`.

But in most cases where you could concatenate string with an int, I think the better solution is to use `string.Format()`:

```
string.Format("i is {0}", i);
```

In your case, it's not as obvious that this way is better, but you start thinking about adding proper punctuation (`i is {0}.`), changing the output slightly in some other way, or supporting localization, the advantages of this way become clear.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `s = i` will not compile when Option Strict is on (default for C#).